# Triangle centers Orthocenter

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> An acute $\triangle ABC$, inscribed in a circle $k$ with radii $R$, is
>   given. Point $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$ and $AH = R$.
>   Find $\angle BAC$. (Answer: $60^\circ$)

[image]

$AD$ $-$ diameter, thus $\angle ACD = \angle ABD = 90^\circ$. Also $HBDC$ is parallelogram because ($HC || BD$, $HB || CD$). It seems useless and I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $P$ be the intersection of ray $HE$ with the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Then, $\angle PAC = \angle PBC = \angle FAC = 90^\circ - C$.

It follows that $\triangle PAH$ is isosceles at $A$, and that $AP = AH = R$. Consequently $\triangle APO$ is an equilateral triangle.

Finally, $$\angle PAO = (90^\circ - C) + \angle CAO = \angle OAB + \angle CAO = A,$$
and we are done.

Comment: Why are the angles $OAB=PAC=90-C$

Comment: $\angle OAB = 90 - \angle ADB = 90 - \angle C$.